# Does the idea of a human being tricking demons (a bit like Constantine) come from folklore or some particular story predating Hellblazer?

Tags: history-of, demons, folklore, constantine, hellblazer

A few years ago, I started reading the [Hellblazer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellblazer) comic-book series, and while I enjoyed it a lot, I felt that the concept of a human being tricking demons (something the character Constantine is quite good at) felt somehow familiar – but after a few years, I still can't find why.

I'm wondering if this concept of a human being tricking demons or evil spirits (instead of the traditional "demons tricking humans" concept) comes from folklore or from some particular story, or if Hellblazer is the first instance of this idea. (Which would surprise me, to be honest.)

I'm not looking for a character *exactly* like Constantine, e.g. the character who tricks demons doesn't have to have some sort of magic powers – just tricking evil spirits or demons with wit is enough.

I'm looking for the oldest instance(s) of this idea; if the idea has been developed independently in different cultures, I'm interested in that too.

---

For the definition of "demon", I simply refer to the definition of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon) on it (but I don't have a very strict criteria, so if you have a different criteria than that, I'd be interested to hear about it):

> A demon is a malevolent supernatural entity.

Comment: "The Devil and Daniel Webster" might serve as a starting point, either to set the goal or to understand why it doesn't count.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis which is based on an older Washington Irving story, "The Devil and Tom Walker". I wouldn't be surprised if something fitting the description is in The Odyssey or Gilgamesh...

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DidYouJustScamCthulhu has a lot of examples.

Comment: Gawain tricks the other-worldly Green Knight.

Comment: @JohnHunt I didn't know the story before, After reading a bit about it, as far as I understand it, it turns out that eventually it's Gawain who's tricked (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Gawain_and_the_Green_Knight : «He [The Green Knight] explains that the entire adventure was a trick of the unnamed "elderly lady" Gawain saw at the castle, who is the sorceress Morgan le Fay [...]»), but as the story contains the idea of tricking the Green Knight, I'd accept it if you post it as an answer (even if I find it debatable that Gawain was really successful at his attempt to trick).

Comment: Another question about origin of things "older than dirt"...

Comment: @Mithoron How can I improve the question?

Comment: Well, afaik the site is OK with questions like that... even if there's no way to pinpoint the origin. You could maybe be more specific about what counts as "demons", at least.

Comment: @Mithoron I had no idea that there was no way to pinpoint the origin, that's why I ask the question in the first place. Maybe there are scholars who worked specifically on the subject, I don't know.

Comment: @Mithoron I added a definition of demon, as you suggested.

Comment: I'll mention one of my favorites, Larry Niven's "Convergent Series" from the late '70s.

Comment: @Shawn I realize I did not see your comments before; thanks for the tvtropes link, I did not even think about checking this website! Reading the fairy tales and literature sections, I think my "deja vu" feeling might come from the fisherman & genie story in the Arabian Nights, that I knew before reading Hellblazer (I just did not make the connection before).

Comment: [Rumpelstiltskin](https://sites.pitt.edu/~dash/grimm055.html) was not officially a "demon" but he was at least a malevolent supernatural entity

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the suggestion, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by a [comment from @shawn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283070/does-the-idea-of-a-human-being-tricking-demons-a-bit-like-constantine-come-fro#comment778077_283070), I looked for references to tricking demons in the Ballad of Gilgamesh, and was [able to find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh#Sumerian_poems):

> The lord to the Living One's Mountain and Ho, hurrah! correspond to the Cedar Forest episode (Standard Babylonian version tablets II–V). Gilgamesh and Enkidu travel with other men to the Forest of Cedar. There, trapped by Huwawa, *(spoiler alert if you've been meaning to read it)*

> Gilgamesh tricks him (with Enkidu's assistance in one of the versions) into giving up his auras, thus losing his power.

Huwawa is another name for [Humbaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbaba), described as:

> ...a figure in Mesopotamian mythology. The origin and meaning of his name are unknown. He was portrayed as an anthropomorphic figure comparable to an ogre, giant or demon.

I dare anyone to beat that!

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Next time I have a question like that, I'll check if it's in the epic of Gilgamesh before asking about it :)

Answer (score 5):

#### [Grimms Fairy Tales: 1812 - 1858](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimms%27_Fairy_Tales)

##### Der Bauer und der Teufel (The Peasant and the Devil)

In Germany there is a tale about a farmer, making a deal with the/a devil. The farmer will get everything growing above the soil, and the devil all within the soil. The farmer plants corn. The devil wants to do it again, but this time the devil wants to swap and the farmer plants beets…

So I assume the "tricking evil spirits" is a very old motive in human tales.

- [The tale in German and English language.](https://www.grimmstories.com/language.php?grimm=189&l=de&r=en)

Comment: Rumpelstiltskin!

Comment: This one was simple very lonely ^^ and also so much sure of his own, that it gave the solution itself...